# svn: SSL is not supported

Tags: subversion, ssl

I am trying to check out code on a Unix box in the Z shell. When I run the following command

svn checkout https://svn.example.net/svn/trunk/source build
I get the following error message:

svn: SSL is not supported

The error message is in no way informative so I'd like to see if anyone has had a similar problem and even better if they have a solution. Thanks

Comment: Is SSL supported if you switch to BASH?, i.e do you get the same error returned in BASH?

Answer (score 2):

If you run `svn --version`, you'll see that "handles 'https' scheme" is not listed. You need to recompile Subversion with SSL support (with the serf library, itself built with SSL support).

Comment: Adding to this, neon can also be a possible offender.  See [this blog](http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=651)

Comment: @ECarterYoung This is old. One can build Subversion with either neon (for Subversion < 1.8) or serf.

Comment: @ECarterYoung I've edited my comment: [neon is no longer supported](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#neon-deleted).